# Nearest neighbor search for organized non-projective point cloud

Tags: knn, point-clouds, pcl

I am looking for a fast knn search algorithm for organized point clouds to process data from an Ouster OS0 Lidar sensor.

The basic idea is the following: If we map the organized point cloud to an image (128x1024 in my case), the surrounding pixels for a given pixel are very likely to be the nearest points in a Euclidean sense. So by searching in the pixel neighborhood, one should be able to find the knn much faster than by using a normal kd tree.

So far, I've found [pcl::search::OrganizedNeighbor](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1search_1_1_organized_neighbor.html). This is not applicable due to pcl saying `Input dataset is not from a projective device!` It doesn't really explain what a projective device is.

Apart from this, I could not find any specific algorithm or implementation, even though I think this is a fairly common problem? High-resolution organized Lidar sensors are popular and knn search is used in many applications.

All answers will be appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I use an ouster device as well and I think I have used OrganizedNeighbor on it successfully (you have to destagger the point cloud for sure), but now I cant reproduce it. Also wondering if the panoramic range image of the ouster is actually a valid input for this algorithm, I think it assumes rectilinear projection like a depth camera.

Comment: I haven't looked into this more since then, but did not find a solution yet. I also guess that the algorithm is meant for depth camera-like point clouds.